# Jellyfin with NGinx Proxt Manager

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, jellyfin

I am running a jellyfin instance on my local IP HTTP://192.168.0.98:8096 and I am trying to make it work via Nginx Manager with a custom location of /jellyin

**My configuration so far:**

***This is my main server:***

[image]

This is my Jellyfin location:

[image]

When I try to access via if I access `MYIP.com:PORT` everything works fine on the main server, but if I try to access the jellfin via `MYIP.com:PORT/jellyfin` I will get just an empty white page and nothing else.
Can anyone help me to find out what exactly I am doing wrong?